# Spring DATA, создание метода с множественой выборкой

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate, spring-data

У меня есть сущность message:

```
package ua.samuliak.messenger.entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long id_room;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long id_user;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String value;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "message")
    private Set<Room> rooms;

    public Set<Room> getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }

    public void setRooms(Set<Room> rooms) {
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }

    public Message() {}

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId_room() {
        return id_room;
    }

    public void setId_room(long id_room) {
        this.id_room = id_room;
    }

    public long getId_user() {
        return id_user;
    }

    public void setId_user(long id_user) {
        this.id_user = id_user;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Сущность Room:

```
package ua.samuliak.messenger.entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "room")
public class Room {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long id_user;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "room")
    private Set<User> users;

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    //Зв'язок з месендж
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_message")
    private Message message;

    public Message getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Room() {}

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId_user() {
        return id_user;
    }

    public void setId_user(long id_user) {
        this.id_user = id_user;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Есть контролер:

```
package ua.samuliak.messenger.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import ua.samuliak.messenger.entity.Message;
import ua.samuliak.messenger.service.MessageService;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;

    // <!---- Работа из Message ----!>
    @RequestMapping(value = "/rooms/messages", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Message> getAllMessages(){
        return messageService.getAllMessage();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/room/{id}/messages", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Message> getRoomMessages(@PathVariable("id") long roomID){
        return messageService.findMessagesByRoomId(roomID);
    }

//    @RequestMapping(value = "/room/{id}}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
//    @ResponseBody
//    public void deleteRoom(@PathVariable("id") long id){
//        roomService.remove(id);
//    }
//
//    @RequestMapping(value = "/room", method = RequestMethod.POST)
//    @ResponseBody
//    public Room saveRoom(@RequestBody Room room){
//        return roomService.save(room);
//    }
}
```

И ещё репозиторий:

```
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
    @Query("from message m where m.id_room like %:idRoom%")
    List<Message> findMessagesByRoomId(@Param("idRoom") long idRoom);

}
```

Ошибка логкет:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List ua.samuliak.messenger.repository.MessageRepository.findMessagesByRoomId(long)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:144)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:212)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:435)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:220)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:266)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:252)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: message is not mapped [from message m where m.id_room like :idRoom]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy508.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: message is not mapped [from message m where m.id_room like :idRoom]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1907)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: message is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3704)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3593)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:718)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:574)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
    ... 110 more
```

Сущности Room и Message связанны типом OneToMany.
Проблема заключается в том, что не могу правлиьно создать запрос на выборку всех сообщений из сущности комнаты. То есть по ид комнаты мы находим все меседжи, которые с ней связаны. Возможно я неправильно связи сделал или настраиваю. Помогите пожалуйста!

---

Очень часто вижу вот такой вывод информации (скрин 1), но в базу записан только 1 объект. Как это решить ? Связи неправильно или что ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте в репозитории изменить аннотацию @Query на

```
@Query("from Message m where m.id_room like %:idRoom%")
```

Сущность называется с большой буквы, поэтому и в запросе она должна быть названа корректно

Comment: Спасибо!) Помогло!) Ещё вопрос, дополнил в 1 посте

Comment: @Samuliak это циклические зависимости между объектами(в вашем случае у комнат есть юзеры и у юзеров есть комнаты), и когда jackson начинает сериализовывать их в json - получается такая бурда, он приходит в сущность 1, начинает сериализовывать коллекцию комнат, в комнатах он находит список юзеров, начинает сериализовывать их, а там комнаты, а там юзеры и так далее.. Мы спасались от этого введением DTO, хотя, возможно, есть более приятные решения в виде настроек jackson'a.

Comment: @Victor посоветуйте мне как решить эту проблему ? Возможно вы знаете ссылку на статью или код знаете ?

Comment: @Samuliak http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: @Samuliak если ответ вам помог, пожалуйста, поставьте галку, отметив решением.